# Getting "error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS"

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.    F:\LinqWebChat\LinqWebChat\LinqChat\web.config  50.

Please help me recover from this bug.

Comment: you please have to check if you nested your folders in your solution or may becaused if one folder contains 2 web.config files in it

Comment: Yeah, everything is written in error message.

Answer (score 1):

Look inside the "obj" folder. For some reason sometimes during a build Visual Studio will stick a web.config in there. It caused the error for me. If theres nothing in there then do a search inside the project for *.config.

Answer (score 0):

I get a very similar error sometimes while working in Visual Studio, and performing a solution clean and rebuild helps.

If you're not in VS then this won't apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you add more than one web.config file in your application then you may face the same error.

It may possible that you add web.config in any sub folder of web-site.